# loadModule import breaks in production build in Vite + Vue3 + TS

Tags: typescript, vuejs3, vite, vue3-sfc-loader

I am using vue-3-sfc-loader along with Vite,Vue3 and TS. The problem is when I try to import it like:

```
import { loadModule } from "../node_modules/vue3-sfc-loader/dist/vue3-sfc-loader.esm.js";
```

It throws error that:

```
Could not find a declaration file for module '../node_modules/vue3-sfc-loader/dist/vue3-sfc-loader.esm.js'. 'c:/Users/ams/Desktop/form_ui/form_ui/node_modules/vue3-sfc-loader/dist/vue3-sfc-loader.esm.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
```

This is not really a problem in development but it breaks my build. Has anybody else faced a similar problem or am I importing it wrong?

Comment: If you're using Vite, you shouldn't need `vue3-sfc-loader` at all. What are you trying to accomplish? Vite has SFC support out of the box.

Comment: Well, I need to load SFC components from end-point.  Can I do that with  Vite?